# Antd Popover and Tooltip state synchronisation between each other. Do not show Tooltip when Popover is active

Tags: reactjs, antd

**What needs to be achieved**

A unique content Popover needs to be shown for each cell with button.
Tooltip needs to be visible on hover, and only when there is no opened Popover.

**The problem description**

State overlapping happens when there is a next button click happens right after clicking on first button and vice versa. In another words, "Hover for Tooltip" should not be visible when I click 'Test 2' right after clicking 'Test 1'

2nd component new state comes before older component state becomes falsy [image]

[CodeSandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/popover-tooltip-ls73t3?file=/index.js)

Tried to move the state outside and loop through all the cells to find if any of these cells has 'opened' Popover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change this part of the code in your sandbox to not display the text "Hover for Tooltip"

Initial code in your sandbox

```
  const [arePopoversOpen, setPopoversOpen] = useState(false);

  const handlePopoverOpen = (newIsOpen) => {
    setPopoversOpen(newIsOpen);
  };
```

Changes to be done

```
  const [arePopoversOpen, setPopoversOpen] = useState(false);

  const handlePopoverOpen = () => {
    setPopoversOpen(!arePopoversOpen);
  };
```